# Making Layers change color based on attribute expression in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, layers, dynamic

At the moment I'm working with a dataset that has a count value as the only value in the database.

However, if I add `&VIEWPARAMS:Sex=Male` to the given url from GeoServer, the results change based on this query.

I want to change the layer of GeoServer based on what is given in this query.

For instance, if `Sex=Male` I want the color of the layer to be blue and if `Sex=Female` I want the color to be pink (in order to give a beter representation and eventually split up the rasters).

Does anyone have a solution for this, because I have been looking for days and I have not found any possible solutions?

-EDIT-

Added both pictures the picture in pink is how the dataset for the female set should look like and the blue one is the male set. What I now want to realise is that if I change the url by adding: 'VIEWPARAMS=Sex:male' I want the color of the map to turn blue and if I do 'VIEWPARAMS=Sex:female' I want the color of the map to turn pink. Without adding another kind of command like '&layers=Male_Layer' or '&layers=Female_Layer'. Is this possible in geoserver?

[image: Picture1]
[image: Picture2]

Incase the pictures are not working here are the url's https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTZFN.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwqdM.jpg

Comment: I am at the moment looking at a javascript application to make it possible. If anyone has a really good solution that works in Javascript to parse an URL and then adding something to a substring, getting the substrings back together and then updating it in the URL (all automaticly based on the '&VIEWPARAMS=Sex:female') that would be really awesome I've been looking into it and I'm not experienced with javascript

Answer (score 1):

Because the only attribute in the selected data is count you can't make different colors with one SLD by using filter. I believe that the only alternative is then to have two basic styles which use different default styles. You can configure named styles on server side and select them with WMS url as `&Sex=Male&styles=male`. Or you can add the whole SDL into GetMap request.

Here are two fast ugly examples which should work for you if you have local GeoServer running on localhost:8080 with topp:states demo layer installed. Green output:

[image]

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&TILED=TRUE&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&FORMAT=image/jpeg&LAYERS=topp:states&SRS=EPSG:4326&bbox=-79.828125,36.50857729743935,-73.125,42.032974332441405&SLD_BODY=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%3Csld%3AStyledLayerDescriptor%20xmlns%3Asld%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%22%20xmlns%3Ajava%3D%22java%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20xmlns%3Awfs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fwfs%22%20xmlns%3Axsi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%22%20xmlns%3Axslutil%3D%22de.latlon.deejump.plugin.style.XSLUtility%22%20xmlns%3Adeegreewfs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.deegree.org%2Fwfs%22%20xmlns%3Afo%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FFormat%22%20xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%22%20xmlns%3Aogc%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fogc%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%22%20xsi%3AschemaLocation%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%20http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.opengis.net%2Fsld%2F1.0.0%2FStyledLayerDescriptor.xsd%22%20version%3D%221.0.0%22%3E%0A%3Csld%3ANamedLayer%3E%0A%3Csld%3AName%3Etopp%3Astates%3C%2Fsld%3AName%3E%0A%3Csld%3AUserStyle%3E%0A%3Csld%3AName%3Estates%3C%2Fsld%3AName%3E%0A%3Csld%3ATitle%3Estates%3C%2Fsld%3ATitle%3E%0A%3Csld%3AIsDefault%3E1%3C%2Fsld%3AIsDefault%3E%0A%3Csld%3AFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%3Csld%3AName%3Estates%3C%2Fsld%3AName%3E%0A%3Csld%3ARule%3E%3Csld%3AName%3EbasicPolyStyle%3C%2Fsld%3AName%3E%0A%3Csld%3AMinScaleDenominator%3E0.0%3C%2Fsld%3AMinScaleDenominator%3E%0A%3Csld%3AMaxScaleDenominator%3E4.724409448771654E14%3C%2Fsld%3AMaxScaleDenominator%3E%0A%3Csld%3APolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%3Csld%3AGeometry%3E%0A%3Cogc%3APropertyName%3Ethe_geom%3C%2Fogc%3APropertyName%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AGeometry%3E%0A%3Csld%3AFill%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22fill%22%3E%2300b400%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22fill-opacity%22%3E0.588%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AFill%3E%0A%3Csld%3AStroke%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22stroke%22%3E%23007d00%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22stroke-opacity%22%3E0.588%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22stroke-width%22%3E1%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AStroke%3E%3C%2Fsld%3APolygonSymbolizer%3E%3C%2Fsld%3ARule%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AUserStyle%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3ANamedLayer%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AStyledLayerDescriptor%3E
```

Pink output:

[image]

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&TILED=TRUE&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&FORMAT=image/jpeg&LAYERS=topp:states&SRS=EPSG:4326&bbox=-79.828125,36.50857729743935,-73.125,42.032974332441405&SLD_BODY=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%3Csld%3AStyledLayerDescriptor%20xmlns%3Asld%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%22%20xmlns%3Ajava%3D%22java%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20xmlns%3Awfs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fwfs%22%20xmlns%3Axsi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%22%20xmlns%3Axslutil%3D%22de.latlon.deejump.plugin.style.XSLUtility%22%20xmlns%3Adeegreewfs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.deegree.org%2Fwfs%22%20xmlns%3Afo%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FFormat%22%20xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%22%20xmlns%3Aogc%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fogc%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%22%20xsi%3AschemaLocation%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%20http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.opengis.net%2Fsld%2F1.0.0%2FStyledLayerDescriptor.xsd%22%20version%3D%221.0.0%22%3E%0A%3Csld%3ANamedLayer%3E%0A%3Csld%3AName%3Etopp%3Astates%3C%2Fsld%3AName%3E%0A%3Csld%3AUserStyle%3E%0A%3Csld%3AName%3Estates%3C%2Fsld%3AName%3E%0A%3Csld%3ATitle%3Estates%3C%2Fsld%3ATitle%3E%0A%3Csld%3AIsDefault%3E1%3C%2Fsld%3AIsDefault%3E%0A%3Csld%3AFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%3Csld%3AName%3Estates%3C%2Fsld%3AName%3E%0A%3Csld%3ARule%3E%3Csld%3AName%3EbasicPolyStyle%3C%2Fsld%3AName%3E%0A%3Csld%3AMinScaleDenominator%3E0.0%3C%2Fsld%3AMinScaleDenominator%3E%0A%3Csld%3AMaxScaleDenominator%3E4.724409448771654E14%3C%2Fsld%3AMaxScaleDenominator%3E%0A%3Csld%3APolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%3Csld%3AGeometry%3E%0A%3Cogc%3APropertyName%3Ethe_geom%3C%2Fogc%3APropertyName%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AGeometry%3E%0A%3Csld%3AFill%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22fill%22%3E%23FF0066%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22fill-opacity%22%3E0.588%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AFill%3E%0A%3Csld%3AStroke%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22stroke%22%3E%23007d00%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22stroke-opacity%22%3E0.588%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22stroke-width%22%3E1%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AStroke%3E%3C%2Fsld%3APolygonSymbolizer%3E%3C%2Fsld%3ARule%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AUserStyle%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3ANamedLayer%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AStyledLayerDescriptor%3E
```

One of SLD files without URL-encoding - Yes, it is rather long and only one parameter is changing `<sld:CssParameter name="fill">#00b400</sld:CssParameter>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:java="java" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xslutil="de.latlon.deejump.plugin.style.XSLUtility" xmlns:deegreewfs="http://www.deegree.org/wfs" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
<sld:NamedLayer>
<sld:Name>topp:states</sld:Name>
<sld:UserStyle>
<sld:Name>states</sld:Name>
<sld:Title>states</sld:Title>
<sld:IsDefault>1</sld:IsDefault>
<sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
<sld:Name>states</sld:Name>
<sld:Rule><sld:Name>basicPolyStyle</sld:Name>
<sld:MinScaleDenominator>0.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
<sld:MaxScaleDenominator>4.724409448771654E14</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
<sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
<sld:Geometry>
<ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
</sld:Geometry>
<sld:Fill>
<sld:CssParameter name="fill">#00b400</sld:CssParameter>
<sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.588</sld:CssParameter>
</sld:Fill>
<sld:Stroke>
<sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#007d00</sld:CssParameter>
<sld:CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.588</sld:CssParameter>
<sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</sld:CssParameter>
</sld:Stroke></sld:PolygonSymbolizer></sld:Rule>
</sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
</sld:UserStyle>
</sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: I understand that and that is also what I have done, I have made 3 seperate layers with different colors, however now is the case how to combine those Layers with the 'VIEWPARAM'. I have added all the layer that should be displayed to the Geoserver (which is indeed runned locally), but now I need to be able to make it so that if 'Sex:Male' then he select Layer1 and if 'Sex=Female' he selects layer2. Do you also have a way of doing this?

Comment: Why you do not make a single layer and filter with CQL_FILTER as in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html?

Comment: That is a very interesting solution, but I'm not sure how to get that working in my solution. As the only data that is displayed on each tile is CountAggr (a count of an aggregration value). And the parameter that I want to use is a VIEWPARAM and I'm not sure how to link a VIEWPARAM to the SQL filter. If you have something for that, that would help me out a lot

Comment: Perhaps you need to do some brain-work and think what you are really going to achieve. Sketch for example images showing the desired result with QGIS and add them to your question. However, perhaps you will be happy with this: define green and pink styles on Geoserver side and send your male/female queries for the common "gender" layer either as `&VIEWPARAMS:Sex=Male&styles=green` or `&VIEWPARAMS:Sex=Female&styles=pink`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try to get the pictures running but I'm at the moment having some problems with the layers with &VIEWPARAMS arguement is not working or changing my data anymore so I first need to solve this, I'll update here once I managed to fix that!

Comment: I have added the pictures in my orginal post hopefully this gives some more information!

Comment: Clarifies a lot, I had a rather bad idea about what your aim is. It may be that I do not know how to reach it but I will think about it. Is count range 0-5000 about correct for your cells?

Comment: At the moment it is, as I only use a small data set at the moment. But eventually the total dataset will contain 23million elements, which can either be Male, Female, Unknown/Unisex. And I know that is incredibly huge, I have at the moment made my layer scale from 0~20000 and everything above 20000 has the same color.